# Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-13, intellij-15

I've installed intellij 2021.1 on windows 7 32 bit. While opening intellij I'm getting error as
[image]

I added  java_home variable still not working

Comment: Please try to install again from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html

Comment: Make sure you do not override any VM options or environment variables.

Comment: Try running from the command line per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line and provide the full output.